# frequency band and Bandwidth

Tags: bandwidth

All I know so far is that frequency is how much a signal repeat it self in a given amount of time (usually one second), like shown in the following figure:

[image]

I'm confused with some concepts like frequency range or I think it's the same as frequency band (correct me if I'm wrong), so what does it exactly mean?

As I understood, if the frequency range from 1 kHz to 3 kHz, does that mean that we have a signal that maybe repeat itself  from 1000 times to 3000 time every second?

I saw that the bandwidth of analog signal is the difference between highest frequency and the lowest frequency, so in the above example is 2 kHz does that mean it is the difference between  the maximum repetition and lowest repetition of the signal?

Comment: Hi! It's been a month, and I wonder whether I've answered your question, or whether you need something else?

Answer (score 1):

> As I understood, if the frequency range from 1 kHz to 3 kHz, does that mean that we have a signal that maybe repeat itself from 1000 times to 3000 time every second?

No.

A signal can be composed of many different repeating signals that are added up. So, if you have a sine that repeats 1000 times in a second, and a sine that repeats 3000 times in a second, and you add these two up, you get a signal with energy at 1000 Hz and 3000 Hz.

But not all signals are purely sinusoidal. Those have energy not only at discrete frequencies, but over a range of frequencies.

There's different definitions of it, but essentially, the bandwidth of a signal is the width of the frequency range in which the signal has energy.

The way your material looks, you'll pretty soon learn about the *Fourier Transform* and  what *Power Spectral Density* is. That explains the mathematical foundation of how signals can have a continuous distribution of energy over a range of frequencies instead of just at discrete (i.e. separate, countable) frequencies.